# Field spectra and Eilenberg--MacLane spectra?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

Apparently thanks to a theorem of Hopkins and Smith, every field spectrum splits into a wedge of Morava K-theories, where we allow the cases $K(0) = H \mathbb{Q}$ and $K(\infty) = H \mathbb{F}_p$. I do not understand this result. What about the Eilenberg-MacLane space $H\mathbb{R}$? Either it is not a field spectrum (which weirds me out) or it is a wedge of Morava K-theories (which also weirds me out). How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H\mathbb{R}$ is a wedge of Morava K-theories: it is a wedge of uncountably many copies of $K(0)=H\mathbb{Q}$.  This is because as an abelian group, $\mathbb{R}$ is just a direct sum of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ (pick a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

More generally, in the case of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra, this theorem is just the elementary fact that every field is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$, and thus as an abelian group is a direct sum of copies of them.

Comment: So the ring structure is basically not relevant in the composition? I knew R is a direct sum as a group but not as a ring.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is true only for the underlying spectrum of HR. When you take into account the monoidal structure on HR as a ring spectrum, then you cannot reobtain it from the structure on the wedge of the HQ's. Right?

Comment: That's correct.  The theorem is just about the spectrum, not the ring structure.  In this particular case $H\mathbb{R}$ can be considered as an $E_\infty$ ring-spectrum which is an algebra over the $E_\infty$ ring spectrum $H\mathbb{Q}$.  In general though there is no such nice statement about ring structures--$K(n)$ does not admit an $E_\infty$ ring spectrum structure at all for $n\neq 0,\infty$, and even if you just want an old-fashioned ring spectrum in the homotopy category its multiplication is not unique.